# Perl: Operation not permitted

Tags: perl

One of the older scripts that I didnt write is in Perl, and today part of stopped working. 
I tried to understand what is going on but I know nothing about perl.

Output is as follows:

```
can't unlock rss: Operation not permitted at /home/ec2-user/news/lib/Utils.pm line 107.
```

From code snippet,

```
sub unlock {
    my $ss = shift || ();
    my $feed = shift;
    `kill -9 $_` for @$ss;
    unlink "/tmp/$feed.lock" or die "can't unlock $feed: $!";      #line 107
    1; 
}
```

Strangely, error only occurs on RSS, when other feeds call this sub, they work just fine.
Any suggestions?

**Edit 1**

Other feed has same chmod and works just fine, aka gets deleted

**Edit 2**

From what I gathered, it is a privilege problem.
File in question is created with

```
sub lock
{
    my $feed = $_[1];
    my $pc = [split '[\r\n]+', `ps aux | grep /$feed.pl | grep -v grep`];
    my $ss = [map {/^[-\w]+\s+(\d+).+?\s+Ss\s+/ and $1} @$pc];
    unlock(0, $feed) if @$pc < 2 && -f "/tmp/$feed.lock";
    unlock($ss, $feed) if @$ss && -f "/tmp/$feed.lock";
    die "$feed is already run" if -f "/tmp/$feed.lock";
    return `touch /tmp/$feed.lock`;
}
```

Comment: Deletion of `/tmp/$feed.lock` file is not permitted, not to mention possible design flaw in locking mechanism.

Comment: @mpapec I updated the question a bit. It worked fine for about a year

Comment: Has the behavior of the program that's being killed changed? Does "/tmp/rss.lock" still exist when `unlink` is called? Is "/tmp/rss.lock" still a file, and not a directory?

Comment: It is a file and it exists

Comment: Can in unprivileged user create and remove files in /tmp ? Can you remove the file from the command line (with `rm`) as the same user the script is running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Operation not permitted" is `EPERM`.  [unlink](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/unlink.html) should return this only in these cases:

> [EPERM]
>      The file named by path is a directory, and either the calling process does not have appropriate privileges, or the implementation prohibits using unlink() on directories.
>
> [EPERM] or [EACCES]
>      The S_ISVTX flag is set on the directory containing the file referred to by the path argument and the process does not satisfy the criteria specified in XBD [Directory Protection](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_02).

Likely it is not a directory, and it is normal for /tmp to have the S_ISVTX flag on for security (though perhaps it didn't before?)  So read the Directory Protection link there and see what may be the issue.

Comment: Its a file just checked again, and has same chmod as another process that shares this sub.

Comment: how about same owner and group?  (by process, I assume you mean lock file)

Comment: Permission might be denied if the file is not owned by you OR if the directory is not writable for you.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: an non-world-writable /tmp would be a broken system

Comment: @ysth: you are right, but if it worked before it might just be that some other process broke it by changing the permissions of /tmp. It's not that hard to do it by accident. It might also that it got re-mounted read-only because of some file system error.

Comment: Same owner and group, and why would that change all of a sudden?
@ysth i agree, and I just created a file and it has octal of 664 yet file in question is 644

Comment: update the question, file is created in the same code via lock sub, why would it not be removable though?

Comment: only possible answer I see would be the code changed effective group or user or it was created as non-writeable and your platform checks that (it's implementation-dependent whether it does)?  given an EPERM error, at least.

Comment: though you might try an strace and verify that it is the underlying unlink call failing and not some other thing perl is doing (seems unlikely, though)

Comment: for some reason Perl script creates the file with root ownership not user ownership, so it cant be unlocked. Any way to change that?

Comment: find where it does it and not do it?  it is common for daemons to start as root and change effective user id after some initialization.  check `$>` (effective user id) and `$<` (real user id) when you create and when you try to unlink the file to verify what's going on.

Comment: alternatively, at the time it creates the file, chown it to the user and group that will be in effect when it tries the unlink.

Answer (score 0):

```
sub unlock {
    my $ss = shift || ();
```

Did you mean `shift || []` ?

```
    my $feed = shift;
    `kill -9 $_` for @$ss;
```

How about using the Perl function instead, e.g. `kill(9,@$ss)`

```
    unlink "/tmp/$feed.lock" or die "can't unlock $feed: $!";      #line 107
```

Like a comment said: "Operation not permitted" (EPERM) means exactly that.
If it worked before it might simply be that some other process did a chown of the file or did a chmod of /tmp so that you are unable to delete files there. So please check the owner of the lock-file and the owner and permissions of /tmp.

Comment: `shift || []` would be clearer, but `shift || ()` (a weird way of writing `shift || undef`) works too (because the `@$ss` is equivalent to `@{ $ss //= [] }`).

Comment: @ikegami: Yes, the '|| ()' is an practically an empty statement (except if `$ss` is set to 0 or ''). That's why I assume it was not intended this way.

Comment: @ikegami: Thanks, I fixed the answer. What I mean is EPERM which is "Operation not permitted".